# How do I let someone chain callback methods on my jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I am wanting to to provide some extra functionality to jQuery.post(). I want to be able to check the response from the server and call different callbacks.

For example:

```
$("#frmFoo").postForm("ajax")
    .start(function () { showSpinner(); })
    .success(function () { alert ("Foo saved"); })
    .error(function() { alert ("Foo could not be saved at this time"); })
    .validationError(function() { alert("Please fix foo and try again"); })
    .complete(function() { hideSpinner(); });
```

So I want to be able to send back a consistent JSON object back to the page and based on that JSON object either call success or validationError providing additional info to validationError.

**UPDATE**
It has been a steep learning curve and I am almost 100% sure that I have done something wrong. Below is my attempt at the functionality that I wanted.

```
(function ($) {
     $.fn.postForm = function (url) {
         var options = options || {};
         var formData = this.serialize();
         var validationCb = jQuery.Callbacks("once memory");
         var successCb = jQuery.Callbacks("once memory");
         var errorCb = jQuery.Callbacks("once memory");
         var completeCb = jQuery.Callbacks("once memory");
         var s = jQuery.ajaxSetup({ }, options);
         var callbackContext = s.context || s;
         foo = {
             success: function () {
                 successCb.add(arguments[0]);
                 return this;
            },
             complete: function() {
                 completeCb.add(arguments[0]);
                 return this;
            },
            validationError : function() {
                validationCb.add(arguments[0]);
                return this;
            },
            error: function() {
                errorCb.add(arguments[0]);
                return this;
            }
         };
         $.post(url, formData)
            .success(function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
                 if (!data.Success) {
                     validationCb.fireWith(callbackContext, [data.Message, data.KeyValuePairs]);
                 } else {
                     successCb.fireWith(callbackContext, [data, textStatus, jqXhr]);
                 }
            })
            .complete(function (jqXhr, textStatus) {
                completeCb.fireWith(callbackContext, [jqXhr, textStatus]);
            })
            .error(function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                errorCb.fireWith(callbackContext, [jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown]);
            });
         return foo;
     };
 })(jQuery);
```

So how bad is what I have done? I am not familiar with javascript and jQuery and I am sure that I am breaking some rules that is bound to bite me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very practical to do what you're proposing because it effectively changes the `promise` interface.

Note that much of what you want does already exist if you just return the result of `$.post` to the caller:

```
showSpinner();
$.post({...})
    .done(...)           // aka .success (deprecated)
    .fail(...)           // aka .error (deprecated)
    .always(stopSpinner) // aka .complete (deprecated)
```

So, you have to show the spinner first, but that's barely any hardship, and there's no way to catch the validation error, so that would need to be part of your `.done` function.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain what you mean when you say i am changing the promise interface? Can I not wrap my plugin around the $.post or the ajax method? I don't mind if I need to change the callback names to avoid collisions.

Comment: I also would really like to be able to chain the callbacks in that nice shorthand.

Comment: @uriDium that's the problem - to chain that you either need to augment or replicate something like `$.Deferred()` - you need to pass around an object that maintains a whole list of separate callbacks, and which knows which ones have to be called depending on what your inner `$.post()` call did.

Comment: I will take a look at Deferred. I was looking at the JQuery library and they appear to be using the Deferred object in their ajax function.

Comment: Most of what I want to do is in the post except for the part where I can parse a JSON object to check if it contains validation errors. If it does I can call a different callback instead of success.

Comment: @uriDium yeah, like I said, you'll have to handle that inside `.done`.

Comment: I think i finally get what you are saying when you said that I would have to change the promise interface. It seems that prom@ise only support always, done and error. Is there anyway that I can extend that interface? Sorry I come from a C# background and am quite ignorant.

Comment: @uriDium I don't think there's any practical way to extend the interface.  In any event, you would have to define the circumstances under which a `validationError` is thrown, and you haven't done that.

Comment: I wanted to always return the same JSON object to client. Something that would contain a successful indicator, a string error message and key value pairs of errors. So if the successful indicator is true I call success. If the successful indicator is false, I call validationFail and pass through the error message and an array of key value pairs. The key being the ID of the field and the value being the error message with that field.

Comment: I have updated my question with my attempt at getting the functionality that I wanted. Is there anything screamingly wrong with this?

Comment: @uriDium yeah, that's kinda what I was expecting to see.  Note that the AJAX `.error`, `.success`, `.complete` are deprecated and should be replaced with `.fail`, `.done`, `.always`, etc.

Comment: Oh great, so all in all not a bad effort from javascript noob?

Comment: @uriDium not bad at all.  You do need to put `var` before `foo`, though ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I will accept your answer as the correct one. My reason for not doing that though is that the jqHXR object that gets passed around seems to be a global one. I wasn't sure if my foo object should also be global. I just tried to match what it was wrapping. This might have been a bad idea though.

Comment: jqXHR's definitely aren't global.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct what you want to achieve, you should use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
  url: your_url,
  type: 'POST'
  beforeSend: function(){ showSpinner(); },
  error: function() { alert ("Foo could not be saved at this time"); }
  success: function (data) { 
     if (data.validation == true) { //example of validation, depends on how you send data from backend
       alert ("Foo saved");
       hideSpinner();
     } else {
        alert("Please fix " + data.foo + " and try again"); //again depends on how you send data     
     }
  }
```

Comment: No. You missed the point totally. I want to intercept json and check if for validation and provide hooks to do custom things. I don't know what they are yet and I want other people to be able to do them. I want to make it a plugin for other people in the team to use.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [$.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (or [$.Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/) if you want something really custom), or more generally the [promise pattern](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A). A simple implementation might look something like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.postForm = function (url, options) {
        var options = options || {},
            s = jQuery.ajaxSetup({ }, options),
            callbackContext = s.context || s;

        var formData = this.serialize();
        var post = $.post(url, formData);
        var deferred = post.pipe(function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
            if (!data.Success) {
                // HTTP OK, soft error
                return $.Deferred().rejectWith(callbackContext, [data.Message, data.KeyValuePairs]);
            } else {
                // success
                return $.Deferred().resolveWith(callbackContext, [data, textStatus, jqXhr]);
            }
        }, function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // HTTP error
            return $.Deferred().rejectWith(callbackContext, [errorThrown, {}]);
        });

        deferred.success = deferred.done;
        deferred.error = deferred.fail;
        deferred.complete = deferred.always;

        return deferred;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This does not differentiate between `error`/`validationError`, but gets rid of most of the biolerplate code.

Comment: I need it differentiate between the two.